# Can I create hash index in a partitioned table?

Tags: mysql, hash, data-partitioning

I have a pretty big table with 300 millions records(table storage is about 13GB).

I have partitioned this table into 10 partitions, but every partition still have almost 30 millions records, that makes the `select xxx where column1 = "yyy"` very slow (almost 30s every simple select).

Now I want to speed it up by adding a hash index to `column1` I use for query data, but it turns out very very very slow to add the index.

So I wonder ,is it possible to do that ? And how do I speed up this operation?

Comment: But don't you just have to add the index once?

Comment: It is possible to index a column, but you have a lot of data and there's no way the operation of adding an index on a 30 mil record table is fast. Unless you have superb hardware, most notably the HDD.

Comment: Why HASH instead of BTREE index?

Comment: @raffian, I thought Hash is much faster than btree.

Comment: @MrROY Not in all cases; HASH is faster for key-based look ups, but does not work for range-based selections, comes down to how you're selecting data (mostly)...see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306316/btree-vs-hashtable

Comment: You'd benefit more had you used InnoDB and not MyISAM for storage engine.. Contrary to popular belief, InnoDB isn't slower than MyISAM, and more than not - quite faster.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I finish the `create index` operation with some changes in `my.cnf`, here a brief result:

#### Total time : 2735 seconds.

#### Records : 300 millions (10 partitions, 30 millions record each).

#### Create index using hash.

#### my.cnf:

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096M
sort_buffer_size = 4096M
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You might also want to have mysql-tmp directory set to a ram-disk.